# How to make or generate a large number of the same topic?

Tags: wordpress, web, content-management-system

I'm search for a way to make or generate a large number of sites on the same topic (many product cards, fast loading) ? and be able to integrate with the CRM? Mobile first.
Or how to (not sure) "generate" many CSS?

wordpress seems so heavy?